# Google Cloud Run Proxy IP

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

My use case is to host a chrome selenium webdriver which parses multiple websites with geoblocking enabled. For example, my app would need to crawl website A which only allows traffic from asian countries, another website B which only allows traffic from US.

Currently I can set up a service in a region and create vpc access connector in same region. How do I go about solving my use case above?

to @guillaume blaquiere and @boredabdel: IP configuration is regional not global though
[image]
you can see that i can choose region there

Comment: So you need a fixed IP for outbound traffic from a Cloud Run app ?

Comment: You must have a connector, a cloud nat and an IP in each region. And deploy a Cloud Run service in each region. You can't achieve what you want with a single service. Or you have to use an external proxy service

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere The issue is that IP's assigned to Cloud NAT are not regional, they are Global. If a website uses some geolocation tool to try to figure out where an IP is coming from, GCP IP's will flagged as US based.

Comment: My bad, yes you are right, the location of the IP is dependent of the owner. Here Google Cloud and the IP are all located in Mountain View. The serverless VPC connector is regional but not the IP. So, you have no choice to use a local service that proxy your outgoing traffic.

Comment: so for google cloud, there is no way to crawl a website and be seen as traffic coming for asian countries?

Comment: Hmm, I mean, if [pricing](https://cloud.google.com/armor/#section-7) isn't too big of an issue, you could always use [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/understanding-google-cloud-armors-new-waf-capabilities#:~:text=There%20are%20times) for geolocking access to certain resources. I believe that if you make an exception for what's functioning as your connector, and apply region locking after that exception, it should work fine.

Comment: @fabc I think there's confusion, I want my crawler originated from my cloud run to crawl different geolocked websites (websites geolocked US only, websites geolocked china only, etc)

Comment: If the crawler is counted as an exception (ie the rule that gives it permission to access said sites is of a higher priority than the geolocking), then it's still applicable, is it not? The regions would be geolocked to everyone but the crawler, so the crawler could still do its job

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer for anyone who's in a similar situation:

There are two suggestions that could work for allowing a crawler to go across several geo-locked websites.

1. You could perform the necessary configurations by hand, using one or more proxies to allow the crawler to go from one website to the other without triggering the geo-locking rules.
2. You could use the [Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/identity-security/understanding-google-cloud-armors-new-waf-capabilities#:%7E:text=There%20are%20times) service and set up rules for geo-locking and a rule to allow the crawler to access all of these sites (with the crawler's rule being a higher priority.